# Messages are not being flashed when form errors in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

**I've edited my question to be more clear.** When I validate my form and it has errors, I flash my message but this does not end up rendered in my template:

```
@app.route('doit', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def doit():
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash('success')
    else:
        if form.errors:
            print "You've got errors!"
            flash('You have some errors')
            print session['_flashes']

    return render_template('test.html')
```

My template for displaying messages:

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
    {{ messages }}
    <br/>
    {{ session }}
{% endwith %}
```

When I submit my form with errors, I flash `flash("You have some errors")`, and I DO see `_flashes` in the session holding my error message when I print my session to console:

```
# my console output
You've got errors!
[('message', 'You have some errors')]
```

However, when the template renders, `{{ session }}` does not have `_flashes` at all, and so `get_flashed_messages()` is always an empty list. No message is flashed as a result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay guys, I was being rather dumb (again). Turns out the form was being POSTed through AJAX, but the result of the call was was expecting a JSON format and not the entire HTML template.

I've switched to returning a json response instead, and now it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The function `get_flashed_messages()` returns a list, which you should iterate over and print out the messages within, like this:

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
    {% if messages %}
    <ul>
    {% for message in messages %}
         <li>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
     No messages.
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: The problem isn't with rendering the messages, it's that the messages are never queued into that list in the first place, so it's always empty. For whatever reason , when I loop through `form.errors.items()` and flash each individual message, I expect that they get appended to the list of messages to be flashed. This doesn't happen.

Comment: It's strange, because my initial thought was that `get_flashed_messages` consumed the list and perhaps you'd snuck in a duplicate call, but this turns out not to be the case from my own test. But looking at your answer, I see that the issue is not with Flask, but with whatever front-end you're using (perhaps Angular?) that is expecting a JSON response - this definitely won't be able to use `get_flashed_messages()` as this function is called when the template is first rendered on the server side.